# httptools build fails while setting up rasa nlu

Tags: python, pip, rasa-nlu

Cloned the repo : https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu.git

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

> Building wheel for httptools (setup.py) ... error   ERROR: Complete
>   output from command /Users/mohit/anaconda3/envs/condapy36/bin/python
>   -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/9t/0qgpwgy906z_sww71dnkgkr80000gn/T/pip-install-7hmlhuo6/httptools/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   bdist_wheel -d
>   /private/var/folders/9t/0qgpwgy906z_sww71dnkgkr80000gn/T/pip-wheel-u02mzs5m
>   --python-tag cp36:   ERROR: running bdist_wheel
>
> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>   ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for httptools   Running setup.py clean for httptools   Building
>   wheel for ujson (setup.py) ... error

```
$ pip install -e .
```

> Obtaining file:///Users/mohit/work/research/NLP/Rasa/rasa_nlu ERROR:
>   Error installing
>   'file:///Users/mohit/work/research/NLP/Rasa/rasa_nlu': editable mode
>   is not supported for pyproject.toml-style projects. pip is processing
>   this project as pyproject.toml-style because it has a pyproject.toml
>   file. Since the project has a setup.py and the pyproject.toml has no
>   "build-backend" key for the "build_system" value, you may pass
>   --no-use-pep517 to opt out of pyproject.toml-style processing. See PEP 517 for details on pyproject.toml-style projects.

OS : Mac OS High Sierra

Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

pip 19.1

Answer (score 0):

That's was actually in issue in `pip` (https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6375).

Please install using `pip install --no-use-pep517 -e .` or upgrade `pip` to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

check for visual studio, redists, vc++ and allied syncing up